# When do we put ( ) in export function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When do we put ( ) in export function in JavaScript?
like what is the difference between these code:

```
function Hello() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export Hello
```

and

```
function Hello() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export Hello()
```

Comment: Only the first is valid

Comment: You can do `export const hw = Hello()` if you want to export the string `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @mousetail First one is not valid either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use this

```
function Hello() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export Hello
```

you are exporting your function.. therefore when you import it

```
import {Hello} from "hello.js"

console.log(typeof Hello) // "function"

console.log(Hello()) // "Hello World"
```

if you use this:

```
function Hello() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export Hello()
```

you are calling `Hello` function, and exporting its returning value, but you need to assign it to variable, or export it as default

```
function Hello() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export default Hello()
```

or

```
function HelloFc() {
 return "Hello World"
}
export const Hello = HelloFc()
```

and then import will look like this

```
import {Hello} from "hello.js"

console.log(typeof Hello) // "string"

console.log(Hello()) // Uncaught TypeError: "Hello" is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically both are not working!

If you want to export function Hello, let's use `export { Hello }`.

If you want to export return value of Hello function, let's use `export default Hello()`.